# How to extend a django-shop Product model?

Tags: django, django-shop

I'm trying to create a Product model for an online store using django-shop. Each product may have a number of colours and sizes, and product-colour-size combinations may differ in quantity so I created another  model for colour-size-quantity.

How can I make data from my GoodsDetail table behave as a part of Goods instance subclassing Product? So that I could add the whole caboodle to cart.

Here's my code:

```
from shop.models import Product
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):  
#some code for Category

class Image(models.Model):
#some code for Image

class Size(models.Model):
#some code for Size

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
#some code for Manufacturer

class Goods(Product):
    #name = Product.name
    #unit_price = Product.unit_price
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    serial_n = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    manufact = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, default=1, null=False, blank=True)
    short_decription = models.TextField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True)
    long_decription = models.TextField(max_length=250, default='', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['unit_price']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
#some code for an optional attribute

class GoodsDetail(models.Model):
    goods = models.ForeignKey(Goods)
    COLOUR_CHOICES = (
        (u'blue', 'blue'),
        (u'green', 'green'),
    )
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='', choices=COLOUR_CHOICES)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, default='', blank = True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(max_length=3, default=0)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True, blank=True)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey('ProductAttribute', null=True, blank = True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [
        ["goods", "colour", "size"],
        ]
```

Comment: You just provided your models.py file. You're not showing how you're adding everything to the shopping cart.

Comment: ỳou basically should use `GoodsDetail` as the actual item in your cart, and then use its `goods` `ForeignKey` to access price etc

Comment: Now the problem is, my GoodsDetail subclassing Product has not only the fields I determined, but also fields from Pruduct. And I want those product fields to live in Goods model, so that my GoodsDetail object could get them through a ForeignKey to a Goods instance. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `Goods` shall inherit from `shop.models.product.BaseProduct` and not from `Product`.

Second, you should override the ModelManager in `Goods` and use `shop.models.product.BaseProductManager` or a class derived from thereof.